# How can one reset the post views on a specific Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

How can one reset the number of post views in order to remove a specific page from appearing in the "Popular" pages Wordpress widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party, I know, but I needed to figure this out today, which I did. So in case anyone else needs to know (for reference, I'm running WordPress version 3.3.1):

Page views are stored in the `wp_postmeta` table with a `meta_key` of `post_views_count`. Here's the query I used to find the views of a single post:

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = 'post_views_count' AND 'post_id' = 1234
```

The query returned 2 results. I'm not sure why, but setting the `meta_value` of both to zero did the job for me.